# can i detect the floor of the building using the android mobile phone?

Tags: android

I need to create an indoor navigation system for a hospital which helps patients and doctors. Is there any way to detect the floor using a android mobile phone?

Comment: Please provide more details.

Answer (score 2):

Google's Project Tango (http://get.google.com/tango/) is one approach...but still somewhat immature and only available on certain android devices.

Comment: I second this it has the ability to remember and relocalize it self to any map you train the device to learn. I have used this to localize and make a navigation system in a big room it's quite accurate!

Answer (score 1):

You could use BLE beacons to more precisely locate users around a building. GPS height is only an estimated value and GPS works particularily bad inside.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the height between two floors and hard code the data in application code and use GPS to get the elevation to within a few meters.To get accurate result You have to drop the phone, and use the accelerometer to see how long it falls before hitting the ground.But its not feasible .Hope it helps!